# A problem with polynomials involving Mahler's measure

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

Let $f(x) = a_dx^d + \dots + a_0 = a_d(x-\alpha_1)\cdots(x-\alpha_d)$ be a polynomial with complex coefficients and (possibly multiple) roots $\alpha_i$. Define the *Mahler measure* $M(f)$ and *length* $L(f)$ of a polynomial to be
$$M(f) = |a_d|\prod_{i=1}^d\max\{1,|\alpha_i|\}$$
$$L(f) = |a_d| + \dots + |a_0|.$$
Prove that $M(f) \leq L(f)$.

I found this problem as the Exercise 1.3[1] in the book "Heights of Polynomials and Entropy in Algebraic Dynamics" by Everest and Ward. In the hints they say that the claim is obvious, but I fail to prove it.

Note: There is a proof in Mahler's paper "On some inequalities of polynomials in several variables" (equation (5)) which uses Jensen's formula. That does not seem obvious and, besides, in the above mentioned book the formula comes later than the exercise.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of the Mahler Measure in the mentioned book by Everest and Ward is
$$M(f) = \exp\left(\int_{0}^{1}\ln(|f(e^{2\pi i\theta})|) \; d\theta\right).$$
Using Jensen's inequality one can deduce that this coincides with your definition 
$$M(f) = |a_d| \prod_{i=1}^d \max\{1,|\alpha_i|\}.$$
However, to prove that $M(f)\leq L(f)$ we simply use that $|f(e^{2\pi i\theta})|\leq L(f)$ and obtain 
$$M(f) \leq \exp\left(\int_{0}^{1}\ln|L(f)| \; d\theta\right)=L(f).$$